# Google Maps API - Activating the infowindow of a custom marker

Tags: google-maps, tooltip, listener

I am trying to activate the infowindow for a custom marer, yielding a small description about the marker, I'm having some trouble at the moment, I have the custom marker working but I can't get the infowindow to show.

I tried calling the listener for the marker and storing it in a variable "customMarker", then calling another mouseover listener to activate the infowindow, but I'm having no luck, can anyone help me out?

```
    var map;
    //Creates a custom icon to be placed on the map                                 
    var goldStar = 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/august/PNG/Star%20Gold.png';

function initialize() {

    //Sets the zoom amount for the map, the higher the number, the closer the zoom amount
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 18
    //center : myLatLng
  };

  //The map object itself
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

   var contentString = 'This is a custom toolTip';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
  }); 
  // Tries to find user location using HTML 5
  if(navigator.geolocation) 
  {

    //sets the map to the position of the user using location
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);


      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }

  var customMarker = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng, map);
  });

  //This listener is not working
  //google.maps.event.addListener(customMarker, 'mouseover', function() {
  //infowindow.open(map,customMarker);
    //});
}

function placeMarker(location, map) 
{
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        icon: goldStar,
        map: map,
        title: "custom marker",
        draggable:true
    });
    map.panTo(location);
}
```

Comment: goldStar is not defined...

Comment: Sorry, I actually just didn't include that, it is initialized just before the initialize function, its just my custom marker icon, ill edit my code to reflect that it is there

Comment: Do you want a tooltip or a infowindow?  The tooltip "custom marker" appears for me [with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/jd0n1vyb/)

Comment: Ah, my apologies, it is in fact the infowindow I am looking for, the speech bubble that appears and points to the marker

Comment: You might want to update your title.

Comment: Just done there, do you know a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google.maps.event.addListener function does not return a marker.  This won't work:

```
var customMarker = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
  placeMarker(event.latLng, map);
});
```

Assign the event listener in your placeMarker function to the marker you create (also gives the advantage of maintaining function closure on the marker):

```
function placeMarker(location, map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        icon: goldStar,
        map: map,
        title: "custom marker",
        draggable: true
    });
    var contentString = 'This is a custom toolTip';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });    
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
    map.panTo(location);
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5c10fj0k/)

Comment: This makes much more sense now, thanks a million for taking the time to help